# Make Exchange auto-reply when mail is send to a email address

Tags: exchange-2007

Currently i have a mailbox on exchange server that is being shared amonst several clients. I want the Exchange server reply with a message when someone sends an email to a certain email address. Is this possible as the mailbox is only being used as a shared one(not a public mailbx).

Answer (score 0):

You can also set up your Outlook 2007/2010 to send an automatic response to some or all of the people who send you email. follow below steps

Configure Outlook 2007 for the account that you want to use Auto-Reply feature on.  In Outlook client go to Tools, Rules and Alerts.  Click on New Rule, under Start from blank rule choose Check messages when they arrive and hit Next.  Choose what you need in there and hit Next again.  Choose have server reply using a specific message and click on a specific message link.  Type in desired subject and message.  Hit Finish and you are set to go.